# I have a btnSave button i want to call this btnSave_Click method on click of an input button btnmore through jquery how can i do that

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-2.0

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >

<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Jquery</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">  jQuery(document).ready(function () {

         $('#btnmore').click(function () {  
          $('<%=btnSave.ClientID%>').click(); 
          alert('done');
         $.ajax({type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: '{}',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'Default.aspx/btnSave_Click',
                success: function(result){

                                            alert(result);} });   
         });
        });</Script> 
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:scriptManager id="script1"></asp:scriptManager>
    <div>
        <table>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />

                    <input type="button" id="btnmore" value="More" />
                </td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Server side code**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static string MyMethod()
    {
        return "abc";
    }


    [WebMethod]
    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("abc");
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried by placing a debugger inside your web method to see whether the data is posted or not? is your code working? what errors areyou getting if any??

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use:

```
$('#btnmore').click(function(
    $('#btnSave').click();
});
```

Note that you will need to get the actual name of btnSave, because it will probably be in a naming container.  Something like this should get the correct id:

```
$('<%=btnSave.ClientID%>').click();
```

Comment: can you send me whole code how to do that i have tried wht you told me but not working

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#btnmore').click(function(
    $('#btnSave').click();
});
```

Its work for me.

Comment: $('#btnmore').click(function(){ $('#btnSave').click(); });

Comment: one thing i just want to know i have to write after jQuery(document).ready(function ()

Answer (score 1):

This can be an alternate solution. On the same button you can call 2 click functions; one client side and another server side.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" Text="Save" runat="server" OnClick="btnSave_Click" OnClientClick=" return buttonClientValue()" />
```

`buttonClientValue()` function should return true or false. If returns true than only `btnSave_Click` will be executed, otherwise not.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I like to do. Since you can't really control the ID assigned by ASP.NET, you need some javascript code in the same page as the button you want clicked. you can wrap that code in a function with a known name that you can call from external .js files if need be. But you need to let ASP.NET generate the 'click' function for you:

```
function clickit() {
    <%=this.Page.GetPostBackClientEvent(this.btnSave, string.Empty)%>;
}
```

then elsewhere in your javascript just call clickit()

Comment: Just used this again today. what happens when you try it?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#_btnSave').click(function () {
            $("form").submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```